# VBA Excel 2010 - Embedding Pictures and Resizing

Tags: excel, vba

I've been lurking for a while and found it very helpful, so thanks for the help already!

I'm trying to write a macro to embed images into a worksheet from individual files and resize them, whilst keeping the full resolution of the image intact should it need to be enlarged again. First of all I tried:

```
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(imageName).Select
With Selection.ShapeRange
    .Height = 100
    .Width = 100
End With
```

This essentially inserted a link to the picture and if the image file was removed or the excel file moved to another computer, the link would be broken. Next I tried:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture Filename:=imageName, _
    linktofile:=msoFalse, _
    savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, _
    Width:=100, _
    Height:=100
```

This code also works, but the image is resized to 100 * 100 pixels before insertion, so the original file resolution is lost.

Is there any way to insert image files and *then* scale them down in size, so that the original resolution is retained?

Comment: Just remove the height and width settings? You may also want to use `.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You first load and position the picture in its original size, and in a second step resize it as desired. You only specify EITHER width or heigth to retain the aspect ratio.

```
Sub Test()
Dim MySht As Worksheet
Dim MyPic As Shape
Dim MyLeft As Single, MyTop As Single

    ' position in Pixel relative to top/left of sheet
    MyTop = 50
    MyLeft = 50

    ' alternatively position to the top/left of [range] C3
    MyTop = [C3].Top
    MyLeft = [C3].Left

    ' alternatively position to top/left of actual scrolled position
    MyTop = Cells(Windows(1).ScrollRow, Windows(1).ScrollColumn).Top
    MyLeft = Cells(Windows(1).ScrollRow, Windows(1).ScrollColumn).Left


    Set MySht = ActiveSheet
    Set MyPic = MySht.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\Users\MikeD\Desktop\Untitled.png", _
                msoFalse, msoTrue, MyLeft, MyTop, -1, -1)
    '      ^^^  LinkTo    SaveWith                -1 = keep size

    ' now resize pic
    MyPic.Height = 100

End Sub
```

... and try to avoid `.Select` ... `Dim` the objects you need and use them.

Comment: Thanks, that worked fantastically! I didn't realise you could set an object as a variable WHILST inserting it, which is where I was struggling in the For-Next loop I'm using. That helped a lot, thanks again!

Comment: on a side note you can also assign it like this: set mypic = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(imageName).Shaperange(1)