# Excel VBA msoScaleFromTopLeft not working for me

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using Excel 2016 with Windows 10 and I insert a picture in cell `B17` and then want to resize it while keeping the top left corner of the picture in the top left corner of cell `B17`. Some pictures resize to the bottom left corner while others resize to the top right corner. 
I tried using msoScaleFromTopLeft but I still get the same pictures shrunk down to the bottom left or top right.

Here's my macro VBA code:

```
Range("B17").Select

ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(PhotoLocation).Select  'Insert photograph from file.

Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 0.2, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
```

What am I missing?
Can someone please help me with this or suggest an alternative method to do what I want?

Comment: Take a look at the following link... the answer places the image relative to a range   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073463/vba-excel-2010-embedding-pictures-and-resizing

Comment: @wayne Please see comments below. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something different, you could `Set` an object to the picture you insert (without using `Select` and `Selection`).

Afterwards, you can modify it's properties using `With myPic`, and nested properties below.

**Code**

```
Sub SetPics()

Dim myPic As Picture
Dim PhotoLocation As String
Dim Rng As Range

Set Rng = Range("B17")

Set myPic = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(PhotoLocation)
With myPic
    .ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 0.2, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    .Top = Rows(Rng.Row).Top
    .Left = Columns(Rng.Column).Left
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @Wenger1988 did you take a look at my answer above ? let me know if the code works as you intended

Comment: Thanks for the response but it doesn't work. Both the picture that resizes to the bottom left and the one that resizes to the top right end up with their top left corner in the middle of cell D15 instead of the top left corner of B17.  Is it possible that I don't have something turned on that needs to be?  Wayne G. Dunn's response doesn't work either.

Comment: I think I found the problem. The pictures that I am having trouble with are taller than they are wide. When I insert them into Excel, they appear correctly but show a rotation of 90 or 270 degrees. Excel then seems to determine the internal top left corner based on that. When the top left corner of the picture is in the middle of cell D15, if I change the rotation to 0 or 180, then the top left corner of the picture is exactly in the top left corner of cell B17. But the pictures are then sideways. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Resolved! I used a modified version of what Wayne G. Dunn suggested. Set MyPic = MySht.Shapes.AddPicture(PhotoLocation, msoFalse, msoTrue, InitPicLeft, InitPicTop, -1, -1) to bring the picture in at full size to get the rotation, height and width. I use these to get the height and width that I want and then bring the picture in at the right place with Set MyPic = MySht.Shapes.AddPicture(PhotoLocation, msoFalse, msoTrue, MyPicLeft, MyPicTop, FinalPicWidth, FinalPicHeight) which has the correct height and width. Moving it will cause the same problems seen above. Thanks for your help!