# VBA resize pasted imaged to entire width/height of cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the below code to resize an image when pasted into the active cell.

I want the image to scale to 100% width and height of the cell.
At the moment i can't seem to get this to work. The code does scale the image, but not 100%.

Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False


'Image Script

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L:L")) Is Nothing Then ' <-- run this code only if a value in column L has changed
On Error GoTo 0
     'paste excel table as enhanced metafile, then resize to full width

    ActiveCell.Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth ActiveCell.Width, _
    msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight ActiveCell.Height, _
    msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft


    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: You should add also the other parts of this code to let us help you

Comment: Check [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22075626/1652222) answer.

Answer (score 0):

adapt this code to your problem

```
   ima = activecell.Top 'take the active cell top margin
   imb = activecell.Left 'take thee activecell left margin
   imc = activecell.Height 'take the activecell height
   imd = activecell.Width 'take the activecell width
   With Selection.ShapeRange
        .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse 'ignore aspect ratio of the image
        .Top = ima 'align image to the top margin of the activecell
        .Left = imb 'align image to the left margin of the activecell
        .Height = imc 'resize height to the activecell height
        .Width = imd 'resize width to the activecell width
   End With
   nam = Selection.ShapeRange.Name
   ActiveSheet.Shapes(nam).Placement = xlMoveAndSize 'resize image with the cell
```

I expect this can help you.